# Why Function is not identical to `&` in autocompilation?

Tags: function-construction, compile, core-language

Here is the example, copied from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/705/4742)

```
square = Function[x, x^2];
square1 = #^2 &;
```

the timing and unpacking status shows

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10000}];

AbsoluteTiming[Developer`PackedArrayQ[Map[square, data]]]
AbsoluteTiming[Developer`PackedArrayQ[tmp1 = Map[square1, data]]]

{0.000771589, True}
{0.000748647, True}
```

Now we add external variable into these two definition.

```
a = 1
square = Function[x, x^2 + a];
square1 = #^2 + a &;
```

and time it again, you got

```
{0.0336384, False}
{0.0062035, True}
```

we can see `&` is still autocompiled, while `Function` is not. Why? I think the documentation treats them as identical way of writing. This distinction is oddly subtle, I just found it today. What is bad is that without `Function`, we can not give parameters names, thus less readability.

Comment: To be precise, it seems that `square = Function[x, x^2 + a];` isn't compared **in `Map`**. I think this can be considered as another evidence that the auto-compilation of pure function is still not that stable currently.

Comment: It's not just about autocompilation. `square` is slower than `square1` without compilation. You can use `Trace` to see that there is a significant difference in the evaluation. Autocompilation can be switched of with `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> \[Infinity]}]` and increases the difference in your second case, while it removes the difference in your first case.

Comment: Hi, @Karsten7. I think it is might not be the point. The goal to use `Function` is to make use of autocompilation. When `&` and `Function` both been autocompiled, they are of same speed. If speed is not of concern, then I  can just use `square2[x_] := x^2;`, and in case of `"MapCompileLength" -> \[Infinity]`, `square2[x_] := x^2` is actually faster than `Function`.

Comment: `square2 = With[{a = a}, Function[x, x^2 + a]]` would autocompile properly. Maybe `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` is handled differently?

Comment: @Karsten7. What difference in the evaluation do you see? For me `Trace@Map[square1, data]` and `Trace@Map[square, data]` look identical in the sense of the evaluation.

Comment: `SetSystemOptions[
 "CompileOptions" -> {"CompileReportFailure" -> True, 
   "InternalCompileMessages" -> True}]` can be used to switch on the generation of an error message.

Comment: @Karsten7. good advice on using `With`, thanks!

Comment: @Karsten7. So your setting generate a message "Compilation of Function[x,x^2+a]/@Compile`AutoVar12 failed because a was not a form suitable for the compiler", What does it mean?

Comment: I wouldn't use `Timing`.  Either `AbsoluteTiming` or `RepeatedTiming`. Even if it might not make a difference here, it's unreliable on recent computer systems.  See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14159/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thanks for reminding. Normally, I use `AbsoluteTiming` too. Since the code is copied, unfortunately, I didn't noticed it. I have fixed it now : )

Answer (score 8):

The solution, as suggested by Karsten7, in a comment is to use `With`.

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10000}];

a = 1;
With[{a = a}, square = Function[x, x^2 + a]];
square1 = #^2 + a &

Timing[Developer`PackedArrayQ[Map[square, data]]]
Timing[Developer`PackedArrayQ[tmp1 = Map[square1, data]]]
```

> `{0.000578, True}`
>
> `{0.000528, True}`

Comment: The question asks *why*, perhaps we could elucidate the underlying reason.